# dotenv file is not loading environment variables in express application

Tags: node.js, express

The .env file is in my root folder, and it contains:

```
SECRET_KEY = jakjdhsjd38eu89u1djbcasjbey3hug4rg2u
```

Also in my index.js file (which is also in root) I have used `require('dotenv').config()`.
But still now I can't access `process.env.SECRET_KEY`.
When I did `console.log` it returns `undefined`.
How to overcome it?

Comment: posted a solution, with resource link as to why your configuration was not working.

Answer (score 0):

you are having `extra spaces`,change this

```
SECRET_KEY = jakjdhsjd38eu89u1djbcasjbey3hug4rg2u
```

to this

```
SECRET_KEY=jakjdhsjd38eu89u1djbcasjbey3hug4rg2u
```

source https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv